# Overlapping Divs in HTML

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want the Divs to work relative to each other. The divs are overlapping when I add rows in gridview. You can see the problem in the image. I am not good at html/css. Kindly help me out.

This is the HTML:

```
<section id="section-1" class="content-current" onclick="setTabIndex(1)">
    <div class="left-side">
        <div class="women_main">...</div>
        <br />
    </div>
    <div class="right-side">
        <div class="w_content">...</div>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div class="women_main">...</div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.right-side {
width:50%;
float:right;
margin-top:0px;
padding-top:0px;
}

.left-side{
width:50%;
float:left;
}


.women_main {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(37, 37, 37, 0.39);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(37, 37, 37, 0.39);
padding: 1em;
border: 2px solid #e3e3e3 !important;
}
```

Comment: You know that this is a CSS issue and you haven't shared the CSS. How's this fair?

Comment: please provide proper code

Comment: you need to clear the float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really `clear` the `float`s. Don't give so many `<br />` for getting to the right layout. The solution is to use `clear: both` on the `.women_main`.

Initial Look:

```css
.right-side {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
.left-side {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.women_main {
  clear: both;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(37, 37, 37, 0.39);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(37, 37, 37, 0.39);
  padding: 1em;
  border: 2px solid #e3e3e3 !important;
}
```

```html
<section id="section-1" class="content-current" onclick="setTabIndex(1)">
  <div class="left-side">
    <div class="women_main">...</div>
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <div class="w_content">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="women_main">...</div>
</section>
```

When the right side is too long:

```css
.right-side {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  height: 600px;
}
.left-side {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.women_main {
  clear: both;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(37, 37, 37, 0.39);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(37, 37, 37, 0.39);
  padding: 1em;
  border: 2px solid #e3e3e3 !important;
}
```

```html
<section id="section-1" class="content-current" onclick="setTabIndex(1)">
  <div class="left-side">
    <div class="women_main">...</div>
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <div class="w_content">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="women_main">...</div>
</section>
```

You could find that both adapt correctly to the height.

Comment: Thanks. This Works!

Comment: @EL323 Please make sure you clear the floats in the right way. `:)` You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out on your code and attached herewith the codepen link. Please check, I hope this will help you.

**HTML**

```
<section id="section-1" class="content-current" onclick="setTabIndex(1)">
  <div class="left-side">
    <div class="women_main">... LEFT CONTENT ...</div> 
  </div>

  <div class="right-side">
    <div class="women_main">... RIGHT CONTENT ...</div> 
  </div>
</section>

<section class="two">
  <div class="">... SECTION2 ...</div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.content-current, .two {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid #000;
  height:100px;
}
.left-side {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.right-side {
  width: 49%;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.women_main {

  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(37, 37, 37, 0.39);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(37, 37, 37, 0.39);
  padding: 1em;
  border: 2px solid #e3e3e3 !important;
}
.content-current:after {
  clear:both;
}
.two {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

http://codepen.io/WebTechie/pen/EZxNwJ